# XSLT - How to trim all values in xsl:value-of expressions

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XSLT code with many *xsl:value-of* invokes. And I need to trim whitespaces in all values.
It is very tediously write normalize-space() on every call.
I use template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it gets no effect.
Thanks!
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I think the answer form @Michael Kay is most likely what you are looking for.

- `strip-space elements="*"` removes only nodes with whitespace-ony text
- Building intermediate node set is not necessary if you only intent too get the values without whitespace.
- Perhaps there is only one reason to use the below  "intermediate node set" solution if you have to test (`<xsl:if test=` ) loot of items and would like to avoid to have `normalize-space` in the test condition.

**Original answer below**

```
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

should  help. (Just on the top level of your xlst.)

Update (next try ;-) )
You can build  an intermediate node set without  whitespace  using exsl:node-set.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
            extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="intermediate">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="ws_remove"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($intermediate)/*"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="ws_remove">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="ws_remove"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="text()" mode="ws_remove" >
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match ="root">
        <test>
            <xsl:value-of select="test"/>
        </test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input

```
<root>
    <test> adfd   das    </test>
</root>
```

Generates this output:

```
 <test>adfd das</test>
```

Comment: Sorry wrong answer `strip-space elements="*"` removes only nodes with whitespace-ony text

Answer (score 3):

Putting the normalize-space() call in the template rule for text nodes doesn't work because xsl:value-of doesn't apply the template rule. If you changed `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates/>` (everywhere) then it would work.